# Why am not able to move content elements after installing tx:container together with tx:gridelements in TYPO3 10?

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

[See solution below]

To move a TYPO3 10 website from tx:gridelements to tx:container I installed tx:container and configured it as it should be. Everything works like a charm.
But when I try to move an element (id: 203) into a container-element there occurs an error:

```
2: SQL error: 'Data truncated for column 'colPos' at row 1' (tt_content:203)
```

When I then copy the same element and paste it into the container-element it is shown and works like a charm.

[SOLUTION]
There was also a module called [paste_reference](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/paste_reference) installed and after updating it everything works as it should.

Comment: How old is your extension, when was it last updated? https://github.com/b13/container/commit/9920efeb69f6391228a61b2d7211bf3c400a02ac says some commit was made to the project resolving colPos problem?

Comment: Please check the type of `colPos`-field in your database. In some cases, this error can be the result of a wrong type of input. Gridelements uses *negative* colPos-values for some cases, but `colPos` is defined as unsigned INT in newer TYPO3 versions.

Comment: Thanks, Julian, good hint, but the database was OK – I already deinstalled Gridelements. Rustyjim gave the hint to update Container but it did not solve the issue. But there was the module [paste_refernece](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/paste_reference) that needed to be updated and solved the issue. I updated the question. Thanks anyway!